# How to "unstack" data in SQL in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My table has this shape:

```
UTC_DT              ID  value
-----------------------------
2021-09-29 12:30:00 1   10
2021-09-29 12:30:00 2   20
2021-09-29 12:30:00 3   30
2021-09-29 12:45:00 1   11
2021-09-29 12:45:00 2   21
2021-09-29 12:45:00 3   31
```

I need this shape:

```
UTC_DT              1   2   3
------------------------------
2021-09-29 12:30:00 10  20  30
2021-09-29 12:45:00 11  21  31
```

I can't figure out how to do that. I thought maybe using `PIVOT`, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: I think so, I just don't understand whats happening. I've got some time later this week to work on this again. Thank you for taking the time to edit my question and reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple *conditional aggregation* like so:

```
select utc_dt, 
    max(case id when 1 then value end) [1],
    max(case id when 2 then value end) [2],
    max(case id when 3 then value end) [3]
from t
group by utc_dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a pivot example, here you go:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('2021-09-29 12:30:00', 1, 10),
        ('2021-09-29 12:30:00', 2, 20),
        ('2021-09-29 12:30:00', 3, 30),
        ('2021-09-29 12:45:00', 1, 11),
        ('2021-09-29 12:45:00', 2, 21),
        ('2021-09-29 12:45:00', 3, 31)
    ) AS x(UTC_DT, ID, value)
)
SELECT pvt.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte
) AS src
PIVOT (
    MAX(value)
    FOR ID IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS pvt;
```

It becomes rough when you don't know the set of (in this case) IDs that you want to pivot.